# как сделать, чтоб стринговая строка "5+5-2" выводила результат?

Tags: php

```
<form >
    <input  method="post" name="cash">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$result = $_GET['cash'];
// ... 
echo $result;
```

вводим 5+5-2 -> submit ->отображает 5+5-2
что нужно написать вместо " ... " , чтоб вывело значения вводимого выражения? т.е. цифру "8"

Comment: тут либо парсер искать или `eval('echo 5+5-2')` но `eval()` лучше не использовать с пользовательскими данными.

Comment: @Naumov <form >
    <input  method="post" name="cash">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$result = $_GET['cash'];
// ... //
echo $result;

так а что ввести вместо " ... "  написать?

Comment: @Александр $result = eval($result); по идее так. но с этим лучше не играться. потому что этот код выполняется на стороне сервера

Comment: Народ, а зачто школьная лаба плюсуеться?

Answer (score 2):

Нашол на github решение:
https://github.com/aboyadzhiev/php-math-parser
Установка с помощью composer.phar

`php composer.phar require "aboyadzhiev/php-math-parser": "dev-master"`

установка композера если нет

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55d6ead61b29c7bdee5cccfb50076874187bd9f21f65d8991d46ec5cc90518f447387fb9f76ebae1fbbacf329e583e30') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

далее подгружем в фаил автозагрузку и юзаем библиотеку

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // если вы в той же директории что и вендор
$parser = new \Math\Parser();
$expression = $_GET['cash'];
$result = $parser->evaluate($expression);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '5+5-2';    
$array = [];
    $str = str_split($str);
    for($i=0;$i<count($str);$i++){
        if(preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str[$i])){
            if($i==0)
                $array[0] = $str[$i];
            else
                $array[0] = $array[0] + $str[$i];
        }else if($str[$i] == '+'){  
            $array[0] = $array[0] + $str[$i+1]; 
            $i++;
        }else if($str[$i] == '-'){
            $array[0] = $array[0] - $str[$i+1]; 
            $i++;
        }

    }
    echo $array[0];
```

Comment: На скорую руку написал

Answer (score 0):

Если только вы будете пользоваться этим, то можно так:

```
<form >
    <input  method="post" name="cash">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$result = $_GET['cash'];
echo eval('return '+$result+';');
?>
```

> Использование eval() может быть очень опасно, поскольку позволяет
>   исполнить произвольный код.

Comment: спасибо,но...не только я....((((мне это нужно впихнуть в метод класса, а условии задачи еще о безопасности была речь)))
так, что eval не подходит...(((

Comment: Не понимаю зачем минусить. Я ответил прямо на вопрос. На счет безопазности ничего до этого не говорилось.

Comment: @SkiesX минус что бы новички не скопировали, не берите на свой счёт и на счёт ответа, а это не сработает потому как в eval надо валидный код передать т.е. `eval('return 2+2-1;');` должен быть. Иначе eval null вернёт.

Comment: @Naumov понял. на счет 'return' протупил)